# rethinkdb: Using parent indices on a child table

Tags: indexing, rethinkdb

Let's say I have two tables: `Car` and `Wheel`. A `Car` has many `Wheel`s. `Car` has an indexed field: `Owner`.

Now, if I wanted a **change feed** for all `Wheel`s which are owned by `"Foo"`, then it seems I have to duplicate the `Owner` field on the `Wheel` table and then whenever the parent `Car` changes, I'd need to perform the same update on child `Wheel`s – this feels like a poor solution though.

I tried adding a `Owner` index function on `Wheel` referencing the parent:

```
r.table('Wheel').indexCreate("Owner", function(wheel) {
  return r.table('Car').get(wheel("CarID"))("Owner")
});
```

Though this returns `"Index functions must be deterministic"`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; you have to put `Owner` onto `Wheel`, or else put your wheels into an array in your `Car` table (which is probably more common).  Changefeeds can't include predicates that span multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was afraid of that :( Unfortunately the Car example was only for illustration. In my actual use-case, I'm performing various complex queries on the child table which wouldn't work if they we all in an array on a single parent doc.